# Flash Builder 4: How to make a component wait for an event?

Tags: events, actionscript, components, wait, builder

Here is my problem. I have a windowed application in Flash Builder with some  code and then an image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       xmlns:flexlib="http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/" preinitialize="loadImage()">
    <fx:Script><![CDATA[
        import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    import mx.controls.Image;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;
    import mx.graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder;
    import mx.utils.Base64Encoder;

    private var image:Bitmap;
    private var base64image:String="";
    private var sleepInt:int;

    private function loadImage():void
    {
        var loader:Loader = new Loader;
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
        loader.load(new URLRequest("mypic.jpg"));
        trace("started loading");
    }
    private function getimg():String
    {
        trace("flexlib accessing image ", base64image);
        return base64image;
    }
        private function imageLoaded(event:Event):void
    {
        image = new Bitmap(event.target.content.bitmapData);
        base64image = getBase64FromComponent(image);
        trace("image converted");
    }


    ]]></fx:Script>

    <flexlib:Base64Image value="{getimg()}"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

The flexlib tag should render an image from a string. I want to load an image in the actionscript code, convert it to a string and then draw it. However, as soon as the application starts it attempts to render the string, which is still empty.

The trace is like this, for some reason the getimg() is called twice:
flexlib accessing image
started loading
flexlib accessing image
image converted

As you can see, the image isn't converted until after flexlib tries to draw it. The solution would be to make the flexlib component wait for the imageLoaded event. How can I do this?

---

Thank you for responding, however the applicationComplete event is called after the preinitialize event, and thus only makes things worse:

```
flexlib accessing image  
flexlib accessing image  
started loading
image converted
```

Answer (score 0):

In the WindowedApplication tag change preinitialize="loadImage()" to applicationComplete="loadImage()"